# Harry Potter AU fanfic where Marauders live and OC is Sirius's daughter

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

A few months back I read a fanfic on Wattpad where the main character was Sirius's daughter that he didn't know about.  In the story, she was raised by her psycho crazy mother who had love potioned Sirius into staying with her, but had screwed up a monthly dose, right before she had gotten pregnant, and when she went to tell Sirius, he had left.  All the Marauders are alive in this, and I believe it was a fic for one of the Weasley twins.  A scene I vaguely remember is where she tackled a bludger to stop it from hitting Harry in a quidditch match (she was Gryffindor).  Does anyone know what this fic is?

Comment: For those of us not deeply into HP fanfic, what is "OC"? "Off-camera" is the only thing I can come up with and I'm pretty sure that's not it. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan It stands for "original character"

Comment: What are AU and OC?